# How to transpose sumcum data in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, transpose, cumsum

I have a dataset like this:

| Year | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1905 | New York |
| 1906 | New York |
| 1906 | Boston |
| *** | *** |
| 2021 | Houston |

I wanted to add sumcum, so I did the following:

```
df["Count"]=1 

df['cumsum']=df.groupby(['City'])['Count'].cumsum()
```

And it is working fine, although not sure if this was the best approach.

What I would like to do next is to transpose the data, but also fill all the gaps. Because occurrence of the cities is not consistent (e.g. Boston occurs in 1924 then again in 1928).

I would like to have this:

[image]

How can I make this with Pandas?

Thanks

Comment: I think yours is the best approach. This is exactly how we use the groupby and cumsum funcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Year": {0: 1905, 1: 1906, 2: 1906, 3: 1907, 4: 1908, 5: 1909},
        "City": {
            0: "New York",
            1: "New York",
            2: "Boston",
            3: "New York",
            4: "Boston",
            5: "New York",
        },
    }
)
```

You can do it like this:

```py
new_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts())
    .rename(columns={0: "Count"})
    .sort_values(by=["Year", "Count"], ascending=True)
    .assign(cumsum=lambda x: x.groupby(["City"])["Count"].cumsum())
    .drop(columns="Count")
    .reset_index()
    .pipe(lambda df_: pd.pivot(df_, index="Year", columns="City"))
    .fillna(method="ffill")
    .fillna(0)
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

print(new_df)
# Output
   Year  Boston  New York
0  1905     0.0       1.0
1  1906     1.0       2.0
2  1907     1.0       3.0
3  1908     2.0       3.0
4  1909     2.0       4.0
```

Comment: Hey @Laurent thanks for the reply. Indeed, your solution works great on this small DF. But on bigger one that I'm using, although it is the same structure, I'm getting funny numbers (e.g. cumsum starts at 9, or jumps from 0 to 27 without steps inbetween etc.).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/aThKh3PD) is full DF, if you can have a look and see if your approach would work with my DF?

Comment: I've updated my answer to deal with larger data, works fine now with your full DF.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Laurent. In the meantime, I found a way how to do it, but it needed merges and looping.. definitely not clean and efficient like yours. Impressive.

Cheers